# Why the complexity in MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, html

I looked at the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), identified unnecessary complexity, and wrote my wrapper function for it:

```
  window.observeDom = (element, callback, config) => {
    let conf = config || { childList: true };
    const observer = new MutationObserver(callback.bind(element));
    observer.observe(element, conf);
    return observer;
  };
```

Altho I prefer this function 10x over the original API, I still wonder whether there is an actual measurable performance difference in reusing the `observer` instance to observe different DOM nodes. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get your point, but if you want to use a single callback to observe multiple distinct threads in a DOM this architecture is probably more useful than having another MutationObserver instance for every such thread.

Consider observing all `<a>` elements on a page using common pattern thus requiring single function to react on mutating any of those elements. You might observe `<body>` element and move complexity to your callback for deciding whether some mutation was affecting any of those `<a>` elements you are actually interested in. But that decision logic is implemented in Javascript then instead of running natively in browser. I'd bet this is having an impact on performance.

So you might observe each `<a>` element instead. Your wrapper is then creating quite as many observer instances as there are `<a>` elements in your document. That's impacting memory. And the browser has to iterate over many observers to iterate over every observer's single-item list of observerd nodes which might have another slight impact on performance. In addition by binding callback to node on every observation you actually create as many callback instances as there are `<a>` elements in your document. That's wasting memory in addition.

To observe 1000 `<a>` elements this way there will be 1000 observer instances to be managed by browser, each bound to one out of 1000 differently bound, but actually identically working, function instances. Each observer is controlling one-item list of nodes to observe.

Now, using the very same callback to be registered for observing a bunch of records to be handled equivalently isn't as complex as it seems. The one and only callback might be reduced to handle the expected mutations, only. It won't have to inspect DOM to decide what element has been mutated and whether that's interesting in your case (accessing DOM is always to be considered bottleneck on performance).

To observe the same set of 1000 `<a>` elements using advised API it takes 1 observer instance, 1 function instance and a single list containing 1000 references on nodes to be observed so any mutation is causing invocation of that single function. So, in this case there is only one thing to be managed a 1000 times in memory and that's the association of nodes to be observed with the actual observer.

To conclude, the API is slightly more complex to suit observations of many nodes widely spread over your document without wasting time and memory in Javascript. I'd consider this more beneficial than having a simple API even though the latter might suffice in your very specific use case.